Serial monitor displays question marks and white boxes even though baud rate is correct Arduino Uno
I have been trying to build an electronic drum kit by utilizing piezo sensors and an Arduino Uno. I connected the positive terminal of the piezo in to analog read pin A0 in my Arduino Uno and the negative pin to the ground with 1 1 Mega ohm resistor in parallel. and i used the below code:
#include <MIDI.h>




MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();

const int piezoPin = A0; // Analog pin connected to the piezo
const int threshold = 100; // Minimum value to detect a hit
const int note = 60;       // MIDI note to send (e.g., 60 for C3)

void setup() {
  MIDI.begin(MIDI_CHANNEL_OMNI); // Listen to all MIDI channels
}

void loop() {
  int piezoValue = analogRead(piezoPin); // Read the piezo sensor value
  Serial.println(piezoValue);
  

  

  if (piezoValue >= threshold) {
    MIDI.sendNoteOn(note, 127, 1); // Send a MIDI Note On message
    delay(100);                   // Small delay to debounce
    MIDI.sendNoteOff(note, 0, 1); // Send a MIDI Note Off message
  }
}


I am aware that the Arduino Uno doesn't support MIDI communication over serial port so a third party library was necessary and i utilized the MIDI.h library from FourtySevenEffects from GitHub. and i edited the library to set the baud rate in it to be 115200 because i am using Hairless<->MIDI software with LoopMIDI and Hydrogen Music softwares to convert the MIDI messages from the Arduino into sounds. After i edited the baud rate in the library i added it to a zip file again and i added the library to the arduino and the hairless midi nor the loopMIDI are sensing any midi messages and the serial monitor is printing question marks and white boxes for all values above the set threshold which is 100 (See below Pic).
enter image description here
Also i know getting an Arduino leonardo is the easiest and most logical solution but i'm short on cash these days and i need to work with what i have XD
Changing the Baud rate from the library and adding the Serial.begin(115200) line after the MIDI.begin line but also it didn't work

What is your expected output?

I am expecting normal reading from the piezo sensors to show in the serial monitor and for the hairless midi to sense the midi messages.

Please specify "normal readings". You could try Serial.println(piezoValue, DEC);

When i hit the piezo sensor reads a value above 100 (The Set threshold) the values appear as in the picture. but if i change the threshold and set it to 1000 for example the values appear normally. And by normally i mean as normal numbers not as question marks and symbols.

Definitely add Serial.begin(115200); Then, eventually remove the MIDI stuff, until it works as expected.

That's because you only apply a delay when piezoValue >= threshold. Which means that when it doesn't you are flooding the Serial with a lot of data. Don't do that. If you use the Serial make sure you output a controlled amount of data there, which you can do by adding a delay in the loop function
